# Search a JSON with input from View, then return that data back to view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am learning asp.net web development to build a simple application that takes user input from the view, and uses that input to search a json file for the json object where that value is. Once the object containing the input value has been found I would like to return that object to the view as a table.

DIRECT PROBLEM: Take user input and search a json file for an object that contains the input value.

VIEW

```html
<div class="mainBranch">
    <div class="introduction">
        <h1>Part Pedigree Query</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form class="pure-form">
            <input id="lotNum" type="text" placeholder="Enter Enter Lot#" />
            <br />
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Search The Database</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

MODEL:

```cs
namespace TorajWebService.Models
{
    public class PartInstance
    {
        public int Part { get; set; }
        public int Lot { get; set; }
        public int Temp1 { get; set; }
        public int Humidity1 { get; set; }
        public int Temp2 { get; set; }
        public int Humidity2 { get; set; }
        public int Temp3 { get; set; }
        public int Humidity3 { get; set; }
        public int Dip1 { get; set; }
        public int Dip2 { get; set; }
        public int Dip3 { get; set; }
        public int Dip4 { get; set; }
        public int Dip5 { get; set; }
        public int Dip6 { get; set; }
        public int Dip7 { get; set; }
        public int Dip8 { get; set; }
        public int Dip9 { get; set; }
        public int Dip10 { get; set; }
        public int Dip11 { get; set; }
        public int Dip12 { get; set; }
        public int Dip13 { get; set; }
        public int Dip14 { get; set; }
        public int WaterTempOutMean { get; set; }
        public int Furnace { get; set; }
        public int Defects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Javascript: Just prints the value to console since I don't know how to query my JSON file

```
namespace TorajWebService.Models
$(document).ready(function () {

    var nameInput = document.getElementById('lotNum');

    document.querySelector('form.pure-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

        //prevent the normal submission of the form
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(nameInput.value);
    });


});
```

Current State: 
I can take user input and print it to console

Desire State:
Take user input and return the JSON object that contains the value entered

Comment: And, Where is your controller to manage a web request that ask for the JSON response?

Comment: And there is my problem! I just started learning asp.net and MVC a few weeks ago. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :-)

Comment: Will you always have exactly three temperatures (and 14 Dips)? Probably a better architecture is to have a list (or array) of temperatures (and dips). That way you can store any amount of them. When Temperature and Humidity always go together, make that combination a separate class

Comment: That is a good idea! To be honest, I am not sure what the production values will be consistent. This is a good note to take to my meeting with the production guys and the business analyst. I am an intern still so I often don't consider these things. Thank you for saving me some embarrassment!